# using LIKE to get records that only has a specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of the columns in my SQL table has "~" as a part of a string
I want to select all records that has ~ with a string on either side but **NOT ENDING with** ~

I have tried using LIKE statement e.g

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
     [PNO]
   FROM [MYTABLE] where PNO like  '%~%'
```

The code rightly returns all records with ~

Results are:

```
C799~
C799~001~6907
E066~
E066~001~8558
```

However I want to modifiy the query so that it would only return

```
C799~001~6907
E066~001~8558
```

Thanks.

Comment: What sql database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [PNO]
FROM [MYTABLE] 
WHERE PNO like  '%~%[^~]'
```

In other databases, you would likely use a regular expression, such as `'~.*[^~]$'.

As a last recourse, you can do this with `like` and `not like`:

```
WHERE PNO LIKE '%~%' AND PNO NOT LIKE '%~';
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the wildcard `_` character. The `_` is a wildcard for 1 character. In total this means that you accept strings with a `~` and at least 1 character behind it:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [PNO]
FROM [MYTABLE] where PNO like  '%~_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a second condition to your `LIKE` expression to exclude records ending in tilde:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [PNO]
FROM [MYTABLE]
WHERE PNO LIKE '%~%' AND PNO NOT LIKE '%~';
```